# Reuse web integration of stripe payment gateway in react native

Tags: react-native, webview, stripe-payments

We are building an e-commerce application using react native. Now we need to integrate Stripe payment gateway in it. We already have the web version of the application is available.

So is it possible to reuse the payment gateway integration of the website?
By using the webview?

Like, we will be load a webpage(our site's page) in webview which basically collects the information from user and process the payment. Everything is done by the webpage.

Does this approach have any security issues?

Will it make an issue while publishing the app to playstore or appstore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's web components all use iframes which by design cannot be accessed by 3rd parties, so from a security point of view using a webview with Stripe Elements is just as secure as using them on your website.

As for whether this is an issue with the various app stores, that depends on your business model and what your product is. I suggest you reach out to Google and Apple directly on what you're trying to do, as they both have draconian rules on when you can use a payment processor like Stripe and when you have to use their in-app purchases systems.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. So it won't make a problem if we use the web implementation using webview right? It's an e-commerce app. So using payment gateway won't make much of an issue., I guess

Comment: In that case you should be fine. Stripe only works over HTTPS so you would be just as secure as using the native implementation.

Comment: @PaulAsjes please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180455/how-to-soul-payment-gateway-using-stripe-error-in-react-native